# URLs ignore arguments in GET request (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, get, webapi

I need to write a Web API for this request:

`{apiUrl}/api/sessions/byhour?startTime=2021-06-30T01:00:00&endTime=2021-06-30T03:00:00`

So I have this controller and method:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/sessions/byhour")]
public class LoginStatsByHourController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet, Route("{startTime=0001-01-01T12:00:00}/{endTime=9999-12-31T11:59:59}")]
    public List<SessionEntry> GetSessionEntryByDate(string startTime, string endTime)
    {...}
}
```

I tested this request:

`https://localhost:5001/api/sessions/byhour/2021-07-01T14%3A00%3A00/2021-07-01T16%3A00%3A00`

which essentially equals to:

`https://localhost:5001/api/sessions/byhour/2021-07-01T14:00:00/2021-07-01T16:00:00`

and everything works fine. But when I try this request:

`https://localhost:5001/api/sessions/byhour?startTime=2021-07-01T14:00:00&endTime=2021-07-01T16:00:00`

(notice `?` and `&`). And I discovered that these arguments are ignored and the default ones (`0001-01-01T12:00:00` and `9999-12-31T11:59:59`) are used instead. Why is that so?

Comment: In your case that does not work, you are passing the parameter as query string. This is while you have defined those parameters as route values. What is very strange in your question is that, the request with the query string should actually fail!

Comment: I suggest you to take look at the Model Binding documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: If you would like to more, please join this SO chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237237/room-for-transcendent-and-aleksandr-novik

Comment: @Transcendent you gave a good kick for me realizing what I've written :D

Comment: @Transcendent you solved my issue, thanks for the link! :)

Comment: You are more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[HttpGet]
public List<SessionEntry> GetSessionEntryByDate(string startTime, string endTime)
{...}
```

and call it like this : `https://localhost:5001/api/sessions/byhour/GetSessionEntryByDate?startTime=2021-07-01T14:00:00&endTime=2021-07-01T16:00:00`

for further reading : checkout [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It ignores your arguments, because if you want to use a query string you have to remove "{startTime}/{endTime}" and sometimes ( depends on the version) have to add [FromQuery] attribute to each input parameter

```
[HttpGet]
public List<SessionEntry> GetSessionEntryByDate(string startTime="0001-01-01T12:00:00", 
string endTime="9999-12-31T11:59:59")
    {...}
}
```

If you still want to use MVC routing , try this

```
 [HttpGet("{startTime?}/{endTime?}")]
public List<SessionEntry> GetSessionEntryByDate(string startTime="0001-01-01T12:00:00", 
string endTime="9999-12-31T11:59:59")
    {...}
}
```